# Typescript library 'has no exported member', even though I export it

Tags: typescript

My typescript compiler complains about 'has no exported member', even though I explicitly exported it and IntelliJ can even do the resolution.

So I try to:

```
import { libModuleLoader } from '@simpletests/testlib55';
```

which I export like this:

```
export const libModuleLoader = () => {
   ...
};
```

but I get the error: `src/app/app.module.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/Bersling/Desktop/IT-Projects/angular/tsng2/cons/src/app/node_modules/@simpletests/testlib55/index"' has no exported member 'libModuleLoader'.`

When I click the "go to declaration" button in intellij it also finds the export:

[image]

I'm using Typsescript v2.3.4.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I had **two** `node_modules` directories and in each was the library, and the import always referred to the one I didn't update.

I had one `node_modules` in the application root, and one in the app folder. It always resolved to the app folder, while IntelliJ's "go to declaration" went to the declaration that was actually there.

For me the solution was to remove the `node_modules` in the app folder, since I added it by mistake.

It happens fast, because you simply need to type `yarn add bla` in the wrong location and you already have a `node_modules` in the wrong location, since yarn doesn't care whether a `package.json` is there or not (as opposed to npm). If you want to have multiple `node_modules`, the solution is to always make sure you update and refer to the correct one.

Comment: I don't know you, but I love you.